# CakePHP How to store an image in db and display it?

Tags: image, cakephp, view

I do not know how to store an image in db and display it?

What i want to do is to store image path in db and store the image in /img/ folder and then display it to the user.

In my registration form i am asking user to upload image like this

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('image', array('class'=>'forminput', 'label' => 'Upload Image:', 'type' => 'file'));  ?>
```

and in database type of image field is longblob.

Displaying it to the user like this...

```
<?php echo $this->html->image('Auth.User.image');?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You store the image on the server and in the DB you save only the name of the image.

Usualy the images are stored in **img** folder in **webroot**. When you will display the image you will have something like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image('img' . DS . CakeSession::read('Auth.User.image')); ?>
```

- where **image** is the name of the image you are uploading saved to the image field in the Users table.

Inside the controller you should upload the file as you do normaly in PHP.

```
$file_name = $_POST['User']['name'];
$tmp_file = $_POST['User']['tmp_name'];
if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_file)){ 
    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_file){
        ... 
        $this->data['User']['image'] = $file_name; 
        $this->User->save($this->data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know but what exactly should i do and how? I am new to CakePHP so do not have any idea.

Comment: You should upload the file as you do normal in PHP.
if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_file)){
   if(move_uploaded_file()...
$this->data['User']['$file_name'];
$this->User->save($this->data);

Comment: i edited my answer. is still not clear enough? Do you know PHP?

Answer (score 0):

```
paste it in your controller and change the field and model names accroding to
```

public function add() {

```
    $this->set('status_tbl', $this->Player->Status->find('list'));


        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
             $this->Player->create();
             if(!empty($this->request->data)){

                if(!empty($this->request->data['Player']['image']['name'])){

                $file = $this->request->data['Player']['image']; 

                $ext = substr(strtolower(strrchr($file['name'], '.')), 1); 

                $arr_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'); 


        if(in_array($ext, $arr_ext)){
        $this->request->data['Player']['image'] = $file['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],'uploads/file'.$file['name']);



        $this->Player->save($this->request->data);
        }

                }


        if($this->Player->save($this->request->data)){
        return $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Players',"action"=>'index'));

                }
            }

        }

}
```